# Проблема большой нагрузки Debian

Tags: debian, нагрузка

Есть сервер. На нем по крону выполняется команда. Например, раз в 10 мин запускается vlc, которых сохраняет часть видео. При этом нагрузка на сервер 1-2%. Если я добавляю еще 2 точно таких же процесса - нагрузка 50-60%. Почему?

Comment: На процессор нагрузка?

Comment: да, память нормально